# Cannot create a file in /usr/bin/

Tags: 16.04, root

My OS is Ubuntu 16.4.7 and I found that I cannot create a new file under the path: `/usr/bin` even if I login as a root user. It said that `permission denied`. What should I do to fix this problem? Thanks a lot.

I want to create a file in this path because when I run `sudo apt-get -f install`, they system said

```
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libglib2.0-bin_2.48.2-0ubuntu4.8_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 unable to create '/usr/bin/gapplication.dpkg-new' (while processing './usr/bin/gapplication'): Permission denied
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libglib2.0-bin_2.48.2-0ubuntu4.8_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I wonder if the error is caused because the system cannot create a file in the `/usr/bin` path.

I have checked the root partition is not full, and I have the write permission in the `/usr/bin` file

```
drwxr-xr-x 175 root root 12288 Apr 21 07:35 lib/
```

Comment: Login as root or use the su or sudo command?

Comment: "What should I do to fix this problem?" fix the reason why you believe you need to put a file in `/usr/bin`. I can guarantee you you do not have a need to do so. If you own that binary you use `/usr/local/bin`. Putting something in `/usr/bin` WILL for instance get it deleted if you install a package that wants to put a binary in there with the same name. And use `sudo` to put a file in system directories.

Comment: I use the su command.

Comment: I want to create a file in `/usr/bin` because when I run `sudo apt-get -f  install`, it shows: `Unpacking libglib2.0-bin (2.48.2-0ubuntu4.8) over (2.48.2-0ubuntu4.7) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libglib2.0-bin_2.48.2-0ubuntu4.8_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 unable to create '/usr/bin/gapplication.dpkg-new' (while processing './usr/bin/gapplication'): Permission denied`. So, I am thinking whether it because of the system cannot create a file in `/usr/bin`.

Comment: To fix the problem, you probably will need to find the course first. The root partition could be full, the file system could be damaged and the partition read-only, there could be a problem with your user account ... You or a process not being able to create a file as administrator indicates that there is a problem with your system. In standard Ubuntu, you cannot use the `su` command because the root account by default is disabled. Did you enable it?

Comment: As above, the recommendations, suggestions and WARNINGS are spot on. Adding to this, Ubuntu 16.04 will OUT of SUPPORT in a matter of days!! Whatever you're trying to do is moot at this point.

Comment: This is could be a  prime example of what I meant: the reason for the error could be that it already exists and the system does not understand why it exists as it did not put it there. Do a   `ls -l /usr/bin/gapplication.dpkg-new'` and see if that returns is without an error ;)

Comment: When I run `ls -l /usr/bin/gapplication.dpkg-new`, I got:
`ls: cannot access '/usr/bin/gapplication.dpkg-new': No such file or directory`. But there is a file called `gapplication`. When I run `ls -l /usr/bin/gapplication`, I got
`-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 19008 Mar  3 23:01 /usr/bin/gapplication`